# Store path to directory in C# library

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, resources

It's more "architecture" then "language" question.

I have a class library in my .Net solution, that generates something using images from a directory that is deployed with the application. User has to be able add new images easily, so I can't put them to resources.

This directory is attached to this class library. Is there any way to get its path? AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory for debug returns /bin/debug/, that isn't right of course.

i.e. - my application is installed to C:\Program Files\MyApp. So, path has to be "C:\Program Files\MyApp\ImagesLib".

BUT:

my application is downloaded from subversion and saved to d:\my projects\MyApp. So, path has to be "d:\My Projects\MyApp\ImagesLib".

How to make this path universal? The directory is created from Visual Studio (right click/Add/New Folder)

Comment: What is your question? I cannot get what do you need

Answer (score 2):

I think your architecture needs a rethink.

In the new UAC world you're expected to write to specific locations on a per user or per computer basis. If you install to `Program Files` for example, under UAC trying to write to your install folder may fail (depending on privileges).

Because of this you will need to use `Environment.GetSpecialFolder()` coupled with the `SpecialFolder` enum.

You can read more about these here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

For example, assuming you just want to store on a per computer basis:

```
var base_data_folder = Environment.GetSpecialFolder(SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
var data_folder = Path.Combine(base_data_folder,"MyApplication");
var images_folder = Path.Combine(data_folder,"Images");
```

On my Windows 7 machine this would equate to:

```
C:\ProgramData\MyApplication\Images
```

Comment: That's how it has to work - user chooses the images from ready one. Then he chooses directory for output and clicks "Generate" and it works. It looks easy, but I had problem with loading _the ready ones_ (that will be read-only).